# PL/SQL IF statement and variable declaration

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to make the code posted below work, but I am receiving an error about the `IF` statement:

```
DECLARE 
    a number; 
BEGIN
    SELECT Pers_API.Is_Manager_(10018) INTO a from dual;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN no_data_found THEN a := 0;
END;

IF (a >0) THEN 
    SELECT 1 from dual;
ELSE 
    SELECT 0 from dual;
END IF;
```

In the first block I am declaring an 'A' variable and setting it to 0 (by the way, the API call result will be 0 or 1, nothing else). The first block works fine or - at least - I do think so. But the `IF` block is not working and having this error:

> PLS-00103:Encountered the symbol "IF"

Any help is appreciated.

---

Update: I have tried it this way:

```
DECLARE 
    a number:=0; 
BEGIN
    SELECT Pers_API.Is_Manager_(10018) INTO a from dual;

    IF (:a >0) THEN
        SELECT 1 from dual;
    ELSE 
        SELECT 0 from dual;
    END IF;
END;
```

I received the exception below:

> ORA-01008: not all variables bound

---

Update

In other words, what I am trying to do is:

- if Pers_API.Is_Manager_(10018) returns true (as 1), I have to do another select statement
- if it's false (as 0), I have to return null.

Any other ideas are appreciated.

Comment: remove colon from  the `IF (:a >0)` line

Comment: if i remove the colon I receive this error PLS-00428: an INTO clause expected in this this SELECT statement. the SELECT within THEN and ELSE blocks

Comment: You can't do this in pl\sql block `SELECT 1 from dual`, you have to select a value into a variable

Comment: how to achieve this this, In other words what am trying to do is, if Pers_API.Is_Manager_(10018) returns true (as 1) I have to do another select statement and if its false (as 0) I have to return null. any other ideas are appreciated

Comment: All of your `select`s need to `select into` something. (Also, you don't need to query the dual table to assign a value to a variable, as PL/SQL has an assignment operator `:=`, and PL/SQL doesn't need brackets around `if` conditions.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few objections, if I may.

- there's no need to *select from dual* in order to assign a value to a variable, when that *value* is returned by a function - simply *assign* it
- exception handler seems to be superfluous. You said that the `is_manager_` function returns 0 or 1 and nothing else. Therefore, it'll *always* return something, so - why do you expect that `SELECT` to return `NO_DATA_FOUND`? Besides, such a case should be handled by the function itself (i.e. you have to make sure that it returns 0 or 1 and nothing else)
- the last paragraph you wrote is somewhat strange. You said that - if the function returns 1, you have to run another `SELECT` statement. Otherwise, you have to return **null** (while code you wrote, `select 0 ...` suggests a zero (0), not *null*); so, which one is true?
- also, saying that you have to **return** *something* (null, 0, whatever) suggests that piece of code you wrote should be a function that returns a value. Is that so?

Code that actually *compiles* might look like in this example.

First, a function (based on Scott's schema) that checks whether an employee is a manager:

```
SQL> create or replace function is_manager_ (par_empno in number)
  2    return number
  3  is
  4    /* function checks whether PAR_EMPNO belongs to a manager and returns:
  5       - 1 - employee is     a manager
  6       - 0 - employee is NOT a manager
  7    */
  8    retval number := 0;
  9  begin
 10    select max(1)
 11      into retval
 12      from emp e
 13      where mgr = par_empno;
 14
 15    return retval;
 16  exception
 17    when no_data_found then
 18      return retval;
 19  end;
 20  /

Function created.

SQL>
```

Code you posted, rewritten so that it does something:

- if an employee is a manager, returns his/her salary
- otherwise, it does not

---

```
SQL> declare
  2    a      number := is_manager_(&&l_empno);
  3    l_sal  emp.sal%type;
  4  begin
  5    if a > 0 then
  6       select sal
  7         into l_sal
  8         from emp
  9         where empno = &&l_empno;
 10       dbms_output.put_line('Employee is a manager and his/her salary is ' || l_sal);
 11    else
 12       null;
 13       dbms_output.put_line('Employee is not a manager');
 14    end if;
 15  end;
 16  /
Enter value for l_empno: 7698
Employee is a manager and his/her salary is 2850

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> undefine l_empno
SQL> /
Enter value for l_empno: 7369
Employee is not a manager

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> undefine l_empno
SQL> /
Enter value for l_empno: -1
Employee is not a manager

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

See if you can adjust it so that it fits your needs. If not, do answer to my objections posted at the beginning of this message, and we'll see what to do next.

Comment: yes you are right to have some objection about my code. that was a prototype. and yes if the result of api is 1 I have to run some select queries and 0 will return nothing.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me that what you are really trying to achieve here is to run a query which must use the result obtained from the package function as a condition. If so, the PL/SQL block wouldn't be needed and can be written as a basic select operation.

What is still not clear from your explanation is whether your select query 
`SELECT 1 from dual` is the actual query you are about to use in your code.Generally, in the `select statement`, we use `CASE` expression to evaluate the conditional logic, which essentially does what `IF ELSE` condition was supposed to do to return the desired result.The query  would have a structure of this form,

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN pers_api.is_manager_(10018) = 1 THEN some_expression
        ELSE some_other_expression --If you omit the else condition, it defaults to null when all others are false
    END
    END
as
FROM DUAL;
```

More specifically, if you want to have the resultant expression come from another database table, the queries can take the form

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN pers_api.is_manager_(10018) = 1 THEN some_expression
        ELSE some_other_expression --If you omit the else condition, it defaults to null when all others are false
    END
as
FROM table_to_run_query
WHERE where_clauses = some_values;
```

If you say that your resultant expression from the table involves many other constructs, the challenge would be to compose it in a *single query cleverly* to avoid any PL/SQL at all. That would be achievable, but it will require  that you explain us with some sample data and expected result, as to what  exactly you want,preferably in a new question.

It would not be complete if I don't mention the `REFCURSOR` technique to obtain results from a select query in PL/SQL. It is either through [DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sql.htm#ARPLS73893)(Oracle 12c and above) or using a `REFCURSOR` bind variable running it in SQL* Plus or as Script in other tools (F5).

```
VARIABLE x refcursor;
DECLARE BEGIN

    IF
        pers_api.is_manager_(10018) = 1
    THEN
        OPEN :x FOR SELECT some_columns FROM some_tables;
    ELSE
        OPEN :x FOR SELECT some_columns FROM other_tables;
    END IF;
   --DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(:x); --12c and above
END;
/

PRINT x -- 11g
```

Comment: thank you very much for your efforts. you light a torch on my road.